# html reset button not working on text area

Tags: html

I took this template from a website and done some editing to add more text box and as well add text area and a drop down list.
Im still new in learning html.

I added text area and when i use the reset button it doesn't work on text area and as well on the drop down list.

the reset should be at bottom before form ?

```html
 <form method="POST">
                        <div class="row row-space">
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <label class="label">Name</label>
                                    <input class="input--style-4" type="text" name="name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <label class="label">IC Number</label>
                                    <input class="input--style-4" type="text" name="ic">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row row-space">
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <label class="label">Username</label>
                                    <input class="input--style-4" type="text" name="username">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <label class="label">password</label>
                                    <input class="input--style-4" type="password" name="password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row row-space">
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <label class="label">Home Address</label>
                                    <textarea class="input--style-4" id="myTextarea" rows="2" cols="25" form="myform"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <label class="label">Gender</label>
                                    <div class="p-t-10">
                                        <label class="radio-container m-r-45">Male
                                            <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="gender">
                                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="radio-container">Female
                                            <input type="radio" name="gender">
                                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row row-space">
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <label class="label">Class</label>
                                        <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search">
                                <select name="state">
                                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose class</option>
                                    <option value="M3CS2464A">M3CS2464A</option>
                                    <option value="M3CS2464B">M3CS2464B</option>
                                    <option value="M3CS2464C">M3CS2464C</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="select-dropdown"></div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <label class="label">age</label>
                                    <input class="input--style-4" type="text" name="age">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row row-space">
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <label class="label">Telephone</label>
                                    <input class="input--style-4" type="text" name="phone">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <label class="label">Interest</label>
                                    <input class="input--style-4" type="text" name="ic">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-t-15">
                            <button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--blue" type="submit">Register</button>
                            <button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--blue" type="reset">Reset</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to use Javascript to reset your inputs.

Here's a fiddle to show you how to do it ---> [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nt3sujz7/)

For the HTML :

```
<button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--blue" onclick="clearInputs()">Reset</button>
```

And for the Javascript :

```
function clearInputs() {
   document.getElementById('myTextarea').value = '';
   document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex  = 0;
}
```